# Filtering and looping data in json response swift

Tags: json, swift, for-loop, filter, alamofire

I'm a beginner and still learn about Swift. I wanna get the data only if they have the same ID and also I make a looping using "for". It'll check if there are no data with the same ID anymore, it'll stop looping. Here is my code

```
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, 
     headers: header)
    .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            
            guard let data = response.data else {return}

            do{
                let dataTagihan = try JSONDecoder().decode(Tagihan.self, from: data)
                

                let tagihanId = dataTagihan.data[0].tagihanId
                let memberId = dataTagihan.data[0].memberId
                let saveMember = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(memberId, forKey: "memberId")
                let saveTagihanId = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(tagihanId, forKey: 
                 "tagihanId")
                print("Tagihan Saved \(saveTagihanId)")
                print("MemberId \(saveMember)")
                
                for var item in dataTagihan.data {
                    self.tagihan = dataTagihan.data.filter({ (value) -> Bool in
                        if value.memberId == self.member {
                            item.memberId = self.member!
                        }
                         return value.memberId == self.member
                    })
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
 
            } catch{
                print("error\(error)")
            }
    }
```

I do this code and the result is I only get one data with the same ID and the "for" loop is not working. I really need your help. thank you in advance

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, you are replacing `self.tagihan`. Is that what you want? `dataTagihan.data.filter` already iterates over the array, so you don't have to to put it inside a loop if you are trying to get a filtered array.

Comment: i think you dont need for loop... please remove for loop and then check ...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need for loop as filter is already doing that for you

```
// for var item in dataTagihan.data {
    self.tagihan = dataTagihan.data.filter({ $0.memberId == self.member })
```

`self.tagihan` contains all data whose `memberId` is `self.member`

And then `reloadData`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
```

Comment: the result is still the same. it only show the first data  which has the same id.

Comment: I want if user click each rows in tableview, it will show the different data and in my case right now it only show the first data without check the others if it is have the same member id or not